# How to keep SpamAssassin up to date under CentOS?

Tags: centos, yum, update, spamassassin

I am running CentOS 5.4 with SpamAssassin installed via yum. However the version yum installed was SpamAssassin version 3.2.5 and I am finding that this version has many outdated rules -- including a rule `FH_DATE_PAST_20XX` which marks all email from the year 2010 and forward as spam. Not good. yum says SpamAssassin is up to date -- what can I do to make yum keep SpamAssassin *really* up to date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sa-update` is a the bundled program to update the rules, including changing that rule to 2020 and later dates.

I have cron set to run it once a month to keep my rules updated.

Comment: Will this update to the newer rules? I tried this and it said `current version is 895075, new version is 895075, skipping channel`

Comment: @Josh: run `sa-update -D`. About the 8th line should read something like "using update directory: /some/path". Make sure that path is where you have your rules located (I don't know where it should be on CentOS)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you mention is bug 6269 in Spamassassin.

https://issues.apache.org/SpamAssassin/show_bug.cgi?id=6269

You can check for the rule being right this way:

```
grep FH_DATE_PAST_20XX /var/lib/spamassassin/3.002005/updates_spamassassin_org/72_active.cf
```

(you have to adjust that path if you are not running 3.2.5 spamassassin.

It should look like this if the rule was fixed:

```
header   FH_DATE_PAST_20XX      Date =~ /20[2-9][0-9]/ [if-unset: 2006]
```