# Spamassassin not work

Tags: spam, spamassassin

I set the threshold to 7.5.
But this mail still can't work thought will auto spam.
Any idea?
Thanks.

X-Spam-Flag: YES
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.2.5 (2008-06-10) on
X-Spam-Level: *****
X-Spam-Status: Yes, score=5.9 required=5.0 tests=DNS_FROM_OPENWHOIS,
 FH_DATE_PAST_20XX,HTML_MESSAGE,RDNS_NONE autolearn=no version=3.2.

Answer (score 3):

You need to update your rules, unless the message actually contains a date past 2020, FH_DATE_PAST_20XX shouldn't be triggering (there was a rule fix for this several months ago). Run `sa-update` and it should update your rules. If that's not working for some reason, read up on this post: [Keeping SpamAssassin up to date](https://serverfault.com/questions/136370/how-to-keep-spamassassin-up-to-date-under-centos/136377#136377).

You must not have set the threshold to 7.5, because the header clearly states that 5.0 is it's threshold. You're `local.cf` file should contain a line similar to `required_score 7.5` Be careful there isn't another line with a different score somewhere else in the file.